# Headless LibreOffice very slow to export to PDF on Windows (6 times slow than on Linux)

Tags: python, pdf, docx, libreoffice

I often need to export many (> 1000) .docx documents to PDF with LibreOffice. Here is a sample document: [test.docx](https://gget.it/ov4w/test.docx). The following code works but it's quite slow on Windows (3.3 seconds on average for each PDF document):

```
import subprocess, docx, time   # first do: pip install python-docx 
for i in range(10):
    doc = docx.Document('test.docx')
    for paragraph in doc.paragraphs:
        paragraph.text = paragraph.text.replace('{{num}}', str(i))
    doc.save('test%i.docx' % i)   # these 4 previous lines are super fast - a few ms
    t0 = time.time()
    subprocess.call(r'C:\Program Files\LibreOffice\program\soffice.exe --headless --convert-to pdf test%i.docx --outdir . --nocrashreport --nodefault --nofirststartwizard --nolockcheck --nologo --norestore"' % i)
    print('PDF generated in %.1f sec' % (time.time()-t0))

    # for linux:
    # (0.54 seconds on average, so it's 6 times better than on Windows!)
    # subprocess.call(['/usr/bin/soffice', '--headless', '--convert-to', 'pdf', '--outdir', '/home/user', 'test%i.docx' % i])
```

**How to speed up this PDF export on Windows?**

I suspect much time to be wasted on `"Start LibreOffice/Writer, (do the job), Close LibreOffice"` `"Start LibreOffice/Writer, (do the job), Close LibreOffice"` `"Start LibreOffice/Writer, (do the job), Close LibreOffice"` etc.

Notes:

- As a comparison: here: https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=92274 the export time is said to be either 90ms or 810ms.
- `soffice.exe` replaced by `swriter.exe`: same problem: 3.3 second on average

  ```
  subprocess.call(r'C:\Program Files\LibreOffice\program\swriter.exe --headless --convert-to pdf test%i.docx --outdir ."' % i)
  ```

Comment: same on macOS and Linux

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed, all the time is wasted in starting/quitting LibreOffice. We can instead pass many docx documents **in one call** of `soffice.exe`:

```
import subprocess, docx
for i in range(1000):
    doc = docx.Document('test.docx')
    for paragraph in doc.paragraphs:
        paragraph.text = paragraph.text.replace('{{num}}', str(i))
    doc.save('test%i.docx' % i)

# all PDFs in one pass:
subprocess.call(['C:\Program Files\LibreOffice\program\swriter.exe', 
    '--headless', '--convert-to', 'pdf', '--outdir', '.'] + ['test%i.docx' % i for i in range(1000)])
```

107 seconds total, so it's ~ 107 ms on average per PDF, far better!

Notes:

- It does not work with 10,000 documents because the length of the command line arguments would exceed 32k characters as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381241/what-is-the-subprocess-popen-max-length-of-the-args-parameter/2381726#2381726)
- I wonder if it's possible to have a more interactive way to work with LibreOffice headless:

  - start Writer headless, keep it started
  - send an action like `open test1.docx` to this process
  - send action `export to pdf`, and close docx
  - send `open test2.docx`, then export, etc.
  - ...
  - quit Writer headless

  This works with COM (Component Object Model) with MS Office: [.doc to pdf using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6011115/doc-to-pdf-using-python/6018039#6018039) but I wonder if something similar exists with LibreOffice. The answer seems to be no: [Does LibreOffice/OpenOffice Support the COM Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17796767/does-libreoffice-openoffice-support-the-com-model)

Comment: Posted a solution that handles multiple documents without restarting soffice: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61466307/5100564.

Comment: You can start LibreOffice as a services and use it without starting/quitting time. https://github.com/unoconv/unoserver

Comment: @nhuanvd This is really a good idea, can you post this as a new answer? I think it would be interesting for future reference.